# how to create a table which inserts two tables having same primary key without duplicates and i need all the data

Tags: postgresql, join, merge

Postgres:

```
create table stock(item_id int primary key, balance float);
insert into stock values(10,2200);
insert into stock values(20,1900);
select * from stock;

create table buy(item_id int primary key, volume float);
insert into buy values(10,1000);
insert into buy values(30,300);
select * from buy;
```

results:

```
 item_id | balance
---------+---------
      10 |    2200
      20 |    1900
(2 rows)


 item_id | volume
---------+--------
      10 |   1000
      30 |    300
(2 rows)
```

Now i want another table which include these two table's data.
The new table which has 3 rows of data with item_id(10,20,30) and no duplication

I need query for this; either by merge or join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `insert into ... select` syntax :

```
create table mytable(item_id int primary key, balance float, volume float);

insert into mytable
select distinct stock.item_id, balance, volume
from stock 
inner join buy on buy.item_id = stock.item_id;
```

You can use a different type of join if needed (`left join` or `full join`). In your case, I think you need a `full join`, but since I'm not sure I'll stick with the `inner join` in the example.

Comment: ya i got your point but  i need like

item_id | balance | volume
---------+---------+--------
      10 |    2200 |   1000
      20 |    1900 |
      30 |         |    300 

as output and i need to insert into another table as you did before.

Comment: +1 for guessing better than I did. Not sure about the `distinct` though. `item_id` is unique in both tables.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing:

- that you really want a view rather than a table
- that the values in the 'buy' table are supposed to be deducted from the 'stock'

so here's what I think you are after:

```
create view v_current_stock as
select item_id, sum(balance) as balance
from ( select item_id, balance from stock 
       union all
       select item_id, -volume from buy )
group by item_id;
```

---

EDIT: seems like my guesswork was a bit off (see comments). Perhaps you are looking for a [`full join`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html):

```
create view v as
select * from stock full join buy using (item_id);


select * from v;


 item_id | balance | volume
---------+---------+--------
      10 |    2200 |   1000
      20 |    1900 |
      30 |         |    300
```

Comment: ya i got your point but  i need like

item_id | balance | volume
---------+---------+--------
      10 |    2200 |   1000
      20 |    1900 |
      30 |         |    300 

as output and i need to insert into another table or may be view as you did.

Comment: Thank you somuch for answering me that i want exactly